# SignalR with sliding expiration with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, signalr

I got a problem when using SignalR with sliding expiration with Forms Authentication.
Because of the SignalR keep polling from server, user auth never expired...

I've researched a lot... and found an interesting article from http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#reconcile

They said:

> the user's authentication status may change if your site uses sliding expiration with Forms Authentication, and there is no activity to keep the authentication cookie valid. In that case, the user will be logged out and the user name will no longer match the user name in the connection token.

I need to have user's auth expired if he idle for 20 minutes, but I can't..

any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: split the signalr app and the normal app into two apps, then the signalr app will not effect the authentication of the normal app, to authenticate the signalr requests, send a token generated for the authenticated user

Comment: that's a solution, but I'm afraid my clients will not allow to split it to two..  I suggest my client to use the JQuery-idle-timeout in order to handle the expiration manually. But my client prefer to seek solution within signalr.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I found one method posted on GitHub issues that utilizes an HttpModule to remove the auth cookie at the end of the pipeline. This worked great in my scenario.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2907

```
public class SignalRFormsAuthenticationCleanerModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication application)
   {
      application.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
   }

   private bool ShouldCleanResponse(string path)
   {
      path = path.ToLower();
      var urlsToClean = new string[] { "/signalr/", "<and any others you require>" };

      // Check for a Url match
      foreach (var url in urlsToClean)
      {
         var result = path.IndexOf(url, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
         if (result)
            return true;
      }

      return false;
   }

   protected void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var httpContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

      if (ShouldCleanResponse(httpContext.Request.Path))
      {
         // Remove Auth Cookie from response
         httpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
         return;
      }
   }
}
```